# Setting Apache to run multiple django apps on the same domain with virtual hosts

Tags: python, django, apache

I want to have two different django apps on the same host. This is my `default` virtual hosts configuration file (this works).

```
WSGIPythonHome /home/user/.virtualenvs/project1
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        WSGIDaemonProcess project1 processes=4 threads=10 display-name=%{GROUP}
        WSGIProcessGroup project1
        WSGIScriptAlias /project1 /home/user/project1/project1/wsgi.py
        Alias /project1/static/ /home/user/project1/project1/staticfiles/
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is `WSGIPythonHome` directive which cannot be inside the `VirtualHost` tag. So, I can't have different projects in the same `default` configuration file. It has to be somewhere else.

I tried to disable `WSGIPythonHome` and use `home=/home/user/.virtualenves/project1` parameter in `WSGIDaemonProcess`, instead, as described in the documentation, but my application didn't work (I get an import error while trying to load wsgi.py file. Strangely, my project works fine if I only use `WSGIPythonHome`).

What I want is to have my other django project:

```
WSGIPythonHome /home/user/.virtualenvs/project2
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        WSGIDaemonProcess project2 processes=4 threads=10 display-name=%{GROUP}
        WSGIProcessGroup project2
        WSGIScriptAlias /project2 /home/user/project2/project2/wsgi.py
        Alias /project2/static/ /home/user/project2/project2/staticfiles/
</VirtualHost>
```

But I can't put this in the same `default` file (in /etc/apaches2/sites-available). I tried adding a `default-001` file in there and restarted Apache but it didn't work.

So, where should I put my second django project configuration?

UPDATE. This is my wsgi.py file

```
import os, sys, site
site.addsitedir('/home/user/.virtualenvs/project1/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
activate_this = os.path.expanduser("/home/user/.virtualenvs/project1/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project1.settings")
project = '/home/user/project1/'
workspace = os.path.dirname(project)
sys.path.append(workspace)
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to do this via WSGIPythonHome? Usually you set up the virtualenv in the wsgi file itself, as described in both Django and mod_wsgi documentation.

Comment: I tried this, and it is not working. I have set up correctly the virtualenv in wsgi.py and it works. I am using the same wsgi.py for all my applications and it is working. I have updated my answer to include it. If I don't add the WSGIPythonHome directive, my app is not working.

Comment: instead of `*:80`, have you tried `_default_:80` (without the WSGIPythonHome)

Comment: You can create multiple sites in `sites-available`, each having a different file name. But you also need to enable them, not only restart the server.

Comment: @dan-klasson. Yes, I tried that but I don't know how to make Apache load all vhost configuration files in `sites-available/` directory. I assume I cannot apply `a2ensite`, or can I?

Comment: You sure can. That's what it's for. Then they should show up in `sites-enabled`

Comment: @dan-klasson Great. I thought that `a2ensite` was only for config files regarding different subdomains, only (i.e. sub1.example.com, sub2.example.com, etc). I think it works, now. Can you make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create multiple virtual host configs in Apache. Create a new config file in the folder `sites-available`. Enable that site by running `a2ensite` and then restart Apache.